# Equivalency between pointers and function parameters in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Let me know if any of my following understanding is inaccurate.

1. `MyClass m = new MyClass()` <---> `MyClass * m = new MyClass;`
2. ??? (no C# equivalent) <---> `MyClass m(5,"foo");`
3. `void SomeMethod(ref Widget w)` <---> `void SomeMethod(Widget & w)` or `void SomeMethod(Widget * * w)`
4. `void SomeMethod(Widget w)` <---> `void SomeMethod(Widget * w)`
5. `???` (no C# equivalent) <---> `void SomeMethod(const Widget)`
6. `???` (no C# equivalent) <---> `void SomeMethod(const & Widget)`
7. `void SomeMethod(out Widget w)` <---> ??? (no C++ equivalent)

Comment: Please don't compare C# and C++ on the subject of pointers.  The C# language was designed to reduce the use of pointers, because that's where most safety and problems lie.

Comment: Which "understanding"? :-S

Comment: Suspected Typos: `void SomeMethod(Widget * * w)` should be `void SomeMethod(Widget * w)` and `void SomeMethod(const & Widget)` should be `void SomeMethod(const Widget &)`

Comment: @user4581301: Second correction you're right, first correction the question is right to use a double-pointer, and actually it's the first "equivalent" that should be `void SomeMethod(Widget*& w)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# and C++ are quite different, more than their names would suggest, but I will try anyway:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass() <---> MyClass * m = new MyClass;
```

Roughly equivalent, except that C# will collect `m` after it is no longer in use. With C++ you must remember to `delete` the object. In C++ it is more idomatic to allocate to the stack or use a smart-pointer.

```
??? (no C# equivalent) <---> MyClass m(5,"foo");
```

C# does not give you much control over where objects are allocated. However, it has `struct` types that can avoid heap allocation.

```
void SomeMethod(ref Widget w) <---> void SomeMethod(Widget & w) or void SomeMethod(Widget * * w)
```

These are similar, but in C# `ref` should usually be avoided.

```
void SomeMethod(Widget w) <---> void SomeMethod(Widget * w)
```

The main difference here is that in C++ anyone with a pointer to an object may delete it. In C# the garbage collector handles the deletion. C# is a bit like using `std::shared_ptr`, but with cycle-detection.

```
??? (no C# equivalent) <---> void SomeMethod(const Widget)
??? (no C# equivalent) <---> void SomeMethod(const & Widget)
```

C# does not have a powerful notion of `const` like C++ does. Typically the entire type must be made immutable using the `readonly` keyword on each field.

```
void SomeMethod(out Widget w) <---> ??? (no C++ equivalent)
```

In C++ taking an object by reference can achieve the same as `out` variables. `out` variables are usually bad practice, so this keyword is a form of documentation.

Most importantly, *take the time to understand how code is meant to be written in each language*. Many of the concepts are shared, but to really take advantage of a technology, you should work *with* it, rather than try to force one paradigm into another.